# Another limit from a math contest $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n^2y_n}{3x_n^2-2x_ny_n+y_n^2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, contest-math

Let $(x_{n})_{n\ge1}$, $(y_{n})_{n\ge1}$ be real number sequences and both converge to $0$.
Evaluate $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n^2y_n}{3x_n^2-2x_ny_n+y_n^2}$$

Comment: Just checking. Do you all inhabit the same body? There was this show on cable called the united States of Tara, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_of_Tara

Comment: Note that $\lim z_n$ need not even exist (even if we accept $\pm\infty$ as possible limits)

Comment: @WillJagy: you're funny. If you place your comment in an answer then I'm going to upvote you. (really!) ;) (+1 for comment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof suggested in the post is incomplete since the sequence $(z_n)_n$ could have many behaviours different of the two you cite. What is crucial here is that the denominator never goes close to zero. More quantitavely, note that, for every $(x_n,y_n)$,
$$
3x_n^2-2x_ny_n+y_n^2\geqslant|x_ny_n|.
$$
Hence, if $(x_n,y_n)=(0,0)$, the $n$th ratio $r_n$ is undefined. If $x_ny_n=0$ but $(x_n,y_n)\ne(0,0)$, then $r_n=0$. And if $x_ny_n\ne0$, then $|r_n|\leqslant|x_n|$. Thus, if $(x_n,y_n)\ne(0,0)$ for every $n$ and $x_n\to0$, then $r_n$ is well defined for every $n$ and $r_n\to0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (+1)

Comment: yeah. I did things in a hurry.

Answer (score 4):

By the [AM-GM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), $|3t+1/t|\ge2\sqrt3$. Therefore, $|3t-2+1/t|\ge2\sqrt3-2$.

Thus, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{x_n^2y_n}{3x_n^2-2x_ny_n+y_n^2}\right|
&=\left|\frac{x_n}{3(x_n/y_n)-2+(y_n/x_n)}\right|\\
&\le\frac{|x_n|}{2\sqrt3-2}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, as long as $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n^2y_n}{3x_n^2-2x_ny_n+y_n^2}=0
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your use of $\lim z_n$ is suspicious. Note that $z_n$ can be *any* sequence of positive numbers (just start with arbitrary $z_n$ and let $x_n=\frac1n, y_n=\frac{x_n}{z_n}$ if $z_n\ge1$ and $y_n=\frac1n, x_n=z_ny_n$ if $z_n<1$).

Note that $3x_n^2-2x_ny+y_n^2=2x_n^2+(x_n-y_n)^2\ge2x_n^2$, hence
$$ \left|\frac{x_n^2y_n}{x_n^2-2x_ny_n+y_n^2}\right|\le\left|\frac{x_n^2y_n}{2x_n^2}\right|= \frac{|y_n|}2,$$
which shows that $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n^2y_n}{x_n^2-2x_ny_n+y_n^2}=0.$$

Comment: hmmm, I thought I can go that way. Thanks (+1).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how many of your alters (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_of_Tara ) know Lagrange multipliers, so I will give a bit extra. $3 x^2 - 2 x y + y^2$ is a positive definite quadratic form. Setting it equal to a positive constant gives and ellipse, a bounded figure. As a result, the function $x^2$ is bounded on such an ellipse, and Lagrange Multipliers tells us that $$ x^2 \leq \frac{1}{2} \left( 3 x^2 - 2 x y + y^2 \right)  $$ with the optima occurring where $x=y.$ As a result, except at the origin itself,
$$ \frac{x^2}{3 x^2 - 2 x y + y^2} \leq \frac{1}{2}, $$ and
$$ \left| \frac{x^2 y}{3 x^2 - 2 x y + y^2} \right| \leq  \left| \frac{y}{2} \right| . $$

A little late now. I see that Andre had the better presentation, then deleted it in anguish over not having quite been first. So, as seen elsewhere,
$$  3 x^2 - 2 x y + y^2 = 2 x^2 + (x-y)^2 \geq 2 x^2. $$ Completing the square the other way gives
$$  3 x^2 - 2 x y + y^2 = \frac{1}{3} \left( 9 x^2 - 6 x y + 3 y^2 \right) =  \frac{1}{3} \left( (3x-y)^2 + 2 y^2 \right) \geq  \frac{1}{3} \cdot 2 y^2, $$ and
$$  3 x^2 - 2 x y + y^2 \geq \frac{2}{3}  y^2. $$
So, if either of $x,y$ is nonzero, the denominator is also nonzero and positive. That's called positive definite.

Comment: Oh. At the end of Volcano with Tommy Lee Jones, the little boy looks around at all the people covered in ash and says "They're all the same"

Comment: thanks! (+1 for your joke) :-)

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm not duplicating, but this seems a bit different.  Rewrite the fraction as

$$\frac{y_n}{3 - 2 \frac{y_n}{x_n} + \left ( \frac{y_n}{x_n} \right )^2}$$

There are three cases:

1) $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (y_n/x_n) = 0$.  Then the limit is $(1/3) \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} y_n = 0$.

2)  $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (y_n/x_n) = L \in (0,\infty)$.  Then the limit is

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{y_n}{3 - 2 L + L^2} = 0$$

3) $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (y_n/x_n) = \infty$.  Then the denominator of the fraction goes to zero, and therefore the limit is zero because the numerator also vanishes in the limit.

Comment: thanks for your effort (+1), but you can also get a negative value for $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (y_n/x_n)$. Look at what @did & Hagen von Eitzen wrote. Things are more complicated.

Comment: Of course, the fact that $L$ may be negative doesn't affect the final limit you present in the case $2$, but you wrote $L \in (0,\infty)$. In the $3$rd case you may also have $-\infty$. As @did said, $(y_n/x_n)$ might have many behaviours.

Comment: This is another relevant case out of the cases we showed. Take $x_{n}=\frac{1}{n}, y_{n}=\frac{\sin n }{n}$.

Comment: @Chris'ssisterandpals: Aha, should've written $|L| \in (0,\infty)$.  But, yes, the oscillatory limits make trouble I did not anticipate.  I will need to address this.